# Strange behaviour in object-c IOS 8 on method calling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistatusbar

I have a view controller where

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
     return YES;
}
```

is getting called before

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I am another view controller where the `viewDidLoad` is getting called first and then the `prefersStatusBarHidden`.

I want `prefersStatusBarHidden` to be called before `viewDidLoad`.

Please help!

Comment: i do not think that you have any influence on the order of calling. what do you need that order for?

Comment: You can't guarantee which is called first.

Comment: I need this. I am setting up some views before setting up views I want status bar to be hidden. It is an animation app. With the status bar the initialisation is getting some design distortion.

Comment: you know that your statusbar will be hidden when the viewcontroller comes on screen. isn't that enough to setup your animations with that in mind?

Comment: Actually it does not do like this. First views are coming and then status bar is getting hidden.

Comment: Really unfortunate to get down voted. Not only me, some others also faced the problem.

Answer (score 2):

for a simple view controller in a tab bar controller I got this order for iOS 8.3

```
13:57:46.610 loadView
13:57:46.612 viewDidLoad
13:57:46.612 updateViewConstraints
13:57:46.613 viewWillLayoutSubviews
13:57:46.613 viewDidLayoutSubviews
13:57:46.614 viewWillAppear:
13:57:46.616 prefersStatusBarHidden
13:57:46.616 viewWillLayoutSubviews
13:57:46.616 viewDidLayoutSubviews
13:57:46.712 viewDidAppear:
```

The reason you see the `viewWillLayoutSubviews`/`viewDidLayoutSubviews` calls twice, that any transitioning animation is happening in between.

I would expect that if there is a animation, also the disappearing of a statusbar would be animated and that might be the reason the call for `prefersStatusBarHidden` happens there.

So whatever you want to do in `viewDidLoad` is better suited in  `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

I used this code: https://github.com/vikingosegundo/ofaexample/blob/298c56346f49c467c9f54e9cf18cd5ec604c1fdc/OFAExample/SecondViewController.m

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the order the methods are called:

1. initWithCoder:
2. awakeFromNib
3. willMoveToParentViewController:
4. **prefersStatusBarHidden**
5. preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation
6. loadView
7. prepareForSegue:sender:
8. **viewDidLoad**
9. extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars
10. edgesForExtendedLayout
11. viewWillAppear:

...

Source: https://bradbambara.wordpress.com/2014/07/31/object-life-cycle-uiviewcontroller/

So you need to rethink your architecture so you're not assuming `viewDidLoad` is called before `prefersStatusBarHidden`

Comment: With break points strangely viewDidLoad is called before prefersStatusBarHidden thats what I am combating.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same viewController? Can you check the stacktrace that they are not called manually from somewhere else?

Comment: Yes it is same view controller.

Comment: And you have verified that they are not called manually? Anything other that is different with the view controller or how it's displayed?